# Charge a supercapacitor safely using mobile charger

Tags: supercapacitor

I am not much experienced with electronics. But I am aware that supercapacitors must be charged with lower voltages than rated. I want to make a simple spot welder using this capacitor.

I have the following things. Can someone tell me what is needed (resistors/Schottky-diodes) and how to connect them?

1. [100F 2.7V super capacitor](http://www.samwha.com/electric/product/list_pdf1/db.pdf)
2. 5V 1.0A mobile charger, non branded
3. multimeter for measurements

I want to charge the capacitor at 2V and then short it over nickel strip to weld the strip to 18650 battery terminal.

Comment: This is a bit of an XY-problem, so could you please post the datasheet to the supercap?

Comment: Sorry, but i bought this supercap at aliexpress and unaware of datasheet.
 http://s.aliexpress.com/NBB7J3eU

Comment: Watch out for fake caps.

Comment: Heh yeah, I would not plan on getting 100F out of those :). But that's merely a diversion, let's assume that you can. I was mostly wondering about the maximum currents, but that's not listed.

Comment: The recommendation here, as always, is, "No datasheet? No sale!".

Comment: [Matryoshka capacitor](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/warning-fake-large-electrolytic-on-ebay-!!/).

Comment: @pipe sorry i couldn't catch what you said there.

Comment: Transistor,  i will try to get datasheet. Long Pham, thanks for make me aware of fake caps.

Comment: @dudul Supercaps can have a limit on how much current you can charge or discharge. An answer to your problem can be different depending on the capacitor. At least you've posted what you know.

Comment: @pipe ok. I will update this question when i get this information. Thanks.

Comment: That capacitor terminals don't look heavy enough for spot welding.

Comment: @pipe here is the datasheet: www.samwha.com/electric/product/list_pdf1/db.pdf

Comment: @pipe since i haven't got useful answer yet and no hope what anybody will see this post again, can you answer it after datasheet is provided? Basically i will temporarily connect power to cap while monitoring the voltage using multimeter. Once the cap voltage raches near 2.0V, i will disconnect it and short over nickel strip. Is it enough if i connect a current limiting R in series (also to protect power source)? Sorry for may lack of knowledge still asking these questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use a linear regulator (LM1117) set to 2V. This pair with a current limiting resistor would prevent the regulator from blowing up.

The next step would be to use a 555 timer to drive a PWM signal to a mosfet in between the LM1117 and the cap. This way you can limit the current without the need for a big current limiting resistor.

Comment: Thanks. This answer can be useful to other people who are familiar with electronics. But for me, can you tell how to charge cap of given specifications and power adapter of 5V 1A with simple resistor and schottkey diode (if necessary). I need to know their specs and arrangement in the circuit

Comment: You could use a power resistor of anywhere between 1 to 20 ohms. You could use this one https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/ARCOL-Ohmite/HS15-10R-J?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtbXrIkmrvidNw3CpujCJIJaqNamLP6NMNLUYbyahjwBw%3d%3d. It is pretty cheap and will get the job done.

Comment: i used 2 ohm 10W ceramic resistor. Thanks!